# React.js Pane seems to crash when an Array of Objects is added to hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, javascript-objects

I'm having an issue with React.js when it comes to adding an array of objects returned by an Axios GET request. The GET request works just fine but the process of trying to add the response to a hook is causing issues.

### Disclaimer

Right away I feel I should explain part of the title where I say the "Pane seems to crash". I said it this way because when the issue occurs, the pane instantly goes blank and no longer shows up in the browser inspector. But at the same time, no error is generated. I have error checking running in the application but there's no information to go on.

## Overview

So far, I have used what I think to be a very standard application with nothing that would be called "fancy".

I've checked out a fair few sources and tutorials ([this one](https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-building-smart-data-table-react/) and [this one](https://dev.to/joelynn/react-hooks-working-with-state-arrays-2n2g) in particular) on the problem and I'm using what I would consider to be a pretty standard approach.

Below is the relevant piece of code.

```
const [bookInfo, setBookInfo] = React.useState([]);
  const tableData = React.useMemo(() => bookInfo, []);
  const tableColumns = React.useMemo(() => columns, []);

  useEffect( async () => {
    try{
      const response = await axios.get(commands.getTenBooks());
      setBookInfo(response.data);

    } catch(e) {
      console.log("Error", e.stack);
      console.log("Error", e.name);
      console.log("Error", e.message);
    } finally {
      console.log(bookInfo);
    }
  });
```

The basic idea is that Axios calls the database and gets a query of ten books. These books are then added to a hook called **bookInfo** which in turn is referenced by the **tableData** hook that provides the data for the table.

The issue occurs once the line `setBookInfo(response.data);` is run. I know this because the page does load properly (albeit with an empty table) with that specific line commented out.

Thanks in advance!

## Update

After a recommendation, I added a dependency array to the the "useEffect" statement and this ended the crashing issue.

```
useEffect(() => {(async () => {
    try{
      const response = await axios.get(commands.getTenBooks());
      setBookInfo(response.data);

    } catch(e) {
      console.log("Error", e.stack);
      console.log("Error", e.name);
      console.log("Error", e.message);
    } finally {
      console.log(bookInfo);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

Though I'm now having an issue actually using the information provided to fill the table. Might there be any tips on how to fix this?

### Minor Update

I fixed that issue. I simply no longer needed the `const tableData = React.useMemo(() => bookInfo, []);` line. I removed it and had the table look for the "bookInfo" hook directly. Issue went away immediately.

Comment: You probably want to add an empty dependency array to that `useEffect`: `useEffect(() => ..., []);`. This ensures it only runs once.

Comment: @Andy So I made the changes and ended up with a block of code that doesn't crash the pane. Though the table still isn't being populated with the data. Any ideas why? I've added the new block of code in an edit to the original question.

Comment: @Andy Never mind that last question. I sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is adding a **dependency array** to a the "useEffect" method. [Here is a link](https://devtrium.com/posts/dependency-arrays) to learn more about them and what they do.

The final code for my component's "useEffect" was...

```
const [bookInfo, setBookInfo] = React.useState([]);
  const tableColumns = React.useMemo(() => columns, []);

  useEffect(() => {(async () => {
    try{
      const response = await axios.get(commands.getTenBooks());
      setBookInfo(response.data);

    } catch(e) {
      console.log("Error", e.stack);
      console.log("Error", e.name);
      console.log("Error", e.message);
    } finally {
      console.log(bookInfo);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```